# Google Recorder Transcript not working

Tags: google-pixel, pixel-experience

I have a Pixel 3a which I recently updated to Android 13 using Pixel Experience. Before updating Android, Google Recorder transcripts worked, though unfortunately I have no more details. Since updating Android, Live Transcribe works, as does Live Captions. When I go to *On-device speech recognition* -> *Add a language* there are no languages listed at all under *Your languages* or *Available languages*. When I go to the *Transcription language* setting in Recorder it says that it’s set to *English (US)* but when I open the setting I see the same as *Add a language* above, ie, no languages listed under either *Selected language* or *Available language*.

I have tried changing the language of the phone, what else can I do to try to get Recorder transcripts working?

[image] [image] [image]

Comment: Just a wild guess, but I'm afraid since Google Recorder's transcription is proprietary, it may not work on custom ROMs. Meanwhile, [Live Captions](https://support.google.com/accessibility/android/answer/9350862) and [Live Transcribe](https://support.google.com/accessibility/android/answer/9158064) are generic accessibility features.

Comment: @AndrewT. I' surprised how much _is_ working tbh, eg, magic eraser, unlimited photo uploads.